# Cell formatting in Access 2007 on a continuous form using VBA rather than the format > conditional highlighting option

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently highlighting cells in Access 2007 using the default format > conditional highlighting option, however I'd like to be able to do this in VBA so I can got more detailed conditional formatting in.

Also, when I have a continuous form open there is always a black record at the bottom, that when typed into, creates a new record.  Is there any way to delete this option?

Thanks a lot :)
Tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the AllowAdditions property for the form to No.

[Extending the Functionality of Conditional Formatting in Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139965%28v=office.10%29.aspx)